# How to switch directly to the desired condition without checking other conditions in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, dictionary

I have an python example code as:

Input: (x,y)

```
         if x==0 and y==0:    
            print x+y+1     
         elif x==0 and y==y:    
            print x+y*y+2    
         elif x==x and y==0:    
            print x*x+y+3    
         else:    
            print x*x+y*y+4
```

How can I switch directly to the condition as, if my input is (x,y) = (0,0) it will output 1 without checking other conditions?

I tried this using dictionary as,

Input: (x,y)

```
         def Case1():
               print x+y+1     
         def Case2():      
               print x+y*y+2     
         def Case3():
               print x*x+y+3    
         def Case4():      
               print x*x+y*y+4     

         dict = {(0,0): Case1,
                 (0,y): Case2,
                 (x,0): Case3,
                 (x,y): Case4,
         }  

         dict[(x,y)]()
```

When I tried this with input (x,y) = (0,0), this gives me output as 4 instead of 1. It seems like, my code is checking only for the Case4. What I am doing wrong in the dictionary?

Thanks!

Comment: Are your `y==y` and `x==x` cases supposed to be always true? In your second approach, the `x` and `y` values in the dictionary will be the values at the time of the dictionary's definition, not at lookup time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bogdan explained why you can not use the variables `x` and `y` as keys into your dictionary. When they are both zero, all 4 keys will be (0,0) at definition time, so the dictionary only contains one case. You can probably achieve what you want by using the result of the tests on `x` and `y` as a key into the dictionary instead (untested):

```
case_dict = {(True, True): Case1,
             (True, False): Case2,
             (False, True): Case3,
             (False, False): Case4,
            }  

case_dict[(x == 0, y == 0)]()
```

Note that you should not call a variable `dict`, since this is the name of a built-in type.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you do not quite understand how Python works. A dictionary is not a pattern matching block, as you have in Haskell or Erlang. It is a data structure with *concrete values* inside. You can try to write `print dict` after your definition and see what's inside it.

When you create your `dict`, current *concrete values* of `x` and `y` are used to create the keys. If `x` and `y` happen to be 0 at the time, the `(0,0)` key will be replaced by `(x,y)` (that's why in your case `Case4` is called).

Answer (score 1):

Say x=0 and y=0.  Your final entry in the dict is (x,y):Case4, or 0,0, replacing any previous 0,0.  Then you look up dict[x,y], or really dict[0,0] which calls Case4...this will happen regardless of what x,y is.

Stick to your original `if`.  The code is clear, although you can make it simpler:

```
     if x==0 and y==0:    
        print 1    
     elif x==0:    
        print y*y+2    
     elif y==0:    
        print x*x+3    
     else:    
        print x*x+y*y+4
```